Handling #[non_exhaustive] structs in Rust unit tests with MongoDB and Axum
I'm developing a Rust project using MongoDB. While writing unit tests, I encountered the #[non_exhaustive] attribute used in the MongoDB library.
As I'm mocking UserRepository(mockall) which implements MongoDB functions, I'm unable to mock the result by directly passing UpdateResult because I can't instantiate it.
How can I work around this issue with UpdateResult?
I understand that non_exhaustive serves precisely to prevent you from directly instantiating a struct, but this is a unit test, I need to mock the result of an external lib.
Are aware of this challenge when working with unit testing, but will not implement it for now
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUST-1891
Here is a simplified snippet of the code:
test.rs
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

    use mongodb::results::UpdateResult;

    use crate::{
        modules::user::{repository::MockUserRepository, service::UserService},
        tests::unit::common::get_user_to_test,
    };

    #[tokio::test]
    async fn check_if_set_session_id_in_user() {
        let mut mock_repo = MockUserRepository::new();

        let mock_update_result = UpdateResult { //cannot create non-exhaustive struct using struct expression
            matched_count: 1,
            modified_count: 1,
            upserted_id: None,
        };

        mock_repo
            .expect_update_one()
            .returning(move |_, _, _| Ok(mock_update_result));

        let user_service = UserService::new(mock_repo);

        let mut user = get_user_to_test();

        user.session_id = None;

        assert!(user.session_id.is_none());

        let result = user_service.check_or_add_session(&mut user).await;

        assert!(result.is_ok());
        assert!(user.session_id.is_some());
    }
}

repository.rs
#[automock]
#[async_trait]
pub trait UserRepository {
    async fn update_one(
        &self,
        query: Document,
        update: Document,
        options: Option<UpdateOptions>,
    ) -> Result<UpdateResult, Error>;
    async fn find_one(
        &self,
        filter: Document,
        options: Option<FindOneOptions>,
    ) -> Result<Option<User>, Error>;
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct MongoUserRepository {
    collection: Collection<User>,
}

impl MongoUserRepository {
    pub fn new(collection: Collection<User>) -> Self {
        Self { collection }
    }
}

#[async_trait]
impl UserRepository for MongoUserRepository {
    async fn update_one(
        &self,
        query: Document,
        update: Document,
        options: Option<UpdateOptions>,
    ) -> Result<UpdateResult, Error> {
        self.collection.update_one(query, update, options).await
    }

    async fn find_one(
        &self,
        filter: Document,
        options: Option<FindOneOptions>,
    ) -> Result<Option<User>, Error> {
        self.collection.find_one(filter, options).await
    }
}


#[non_exhaustive] is used precisely to prevent you from instantiating it directly, you shouldn't attempt to do so anyways.

I understand, but this is a unit test, I need to mock the result from an external lib,

"but this is a unit test" - that's not a justification, unit testing does not let you break the rules.

[non_exhaustive] prevents you from creating an instance of the struct by usual methods and instead you should create the instance provided by the update_one() and update_many() functions
In the case of testing you should create your own mock struct :
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct MockUpdateResult {
    pub matched_count: u64,
    pub modified_count: u64,
    pub upserted_id: Option<bson::Bson>,
}
impl From<MockUpdateResult> for UpdateResult {
    fn from(mock: MockUpdateResult) -> Self {
        UpdateResult {
            matched_count: mock.matched_count,
            modified_count: mock.modified_count,
            upserted_id: mock.upserted_id,
        }
    }
}

then implement this custom struct

How does this mock struct solve the problem? You can't construct an UpdateResult, so your From impl won't work.

@ChayimFriedman Update your test code to use the MockUpdateResult and convert it to UpdateResult using the From implementation.

You didn't understand me. This won't compile.

my bad
you can try instead wrapping the UpdateResult in another struct or trait
trait UpdateResultTrait {
fn matched_count(&self) -> u64;
fn modified_count(&self) -> u64;
fn upserted_id(&self) -> Option<&Bson>;
}
then try to implement the UpdateResultTrait for UpdateResult and UpdateResultTrait for MockUpdateResult
